# How does oxygen react to radio waves at 60Ghz?

Tags: radio-frequency

Since there are 3 states of oxygen:

3Σ−g: The ground triplet state

1Δg: The ground singlet state

1Σ+g: An excited singlet state.

What happens to the ground triplet state when it is exposed to the 60 Ghz EM wave? I've read that the radio wave at 60Ghz gets mostly absorbed by oxygen, why is that?
Does the ground triplet state change in to other state when it absorbs 60Ghz radio wave. If so,
how would the body react to these different states? Is it safe to breathe oxygen in singlet state?

Comment: If you are in an area with enough 60GHz radiation to significantly populate excited states of oxygen you have bigger problems than worrying about breathing said oxygen.

Comment: Can you explain

Comment: O2 absorption at the 60 GHz absorption band is a huge topic, both for communication and Earth science (radiometry/upwelling). Last time I checked, there were at least 44 lines with complex pressure dependence. Typically one uses dedicated computer codes which are developed by theory and verified by experiment in order to do any scientific remote sensing of the atmosphere or surface...I don't think a satisfactory answer can be given.

Comment: @JEB Thank you for the answer anyway.